# How to use the sphinx plugin of pybuilder?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pybuilder

I try to create a python package using pybuilder and wonder how to make use of the sphinx plugin. I already initiated a sphinx documentation scaffold via sphinx-quickstart and activated the sphinx plugin within the build.py file of pybuilder.

The following displays my current build.py:

```
# import required packages
from pybuilder.core import use_plugin, init
import os
import sys
import inspect

# import required plugins
use_plugin("python.core")
use_plugin("python.unittest")
use_plugin("python.install_dependencies")
use_plugin("python.flake8")
use_plugin("python.coverage")
use_plugin("python.distutils")
use_plugin("python.sphinx")

# define build attributes
name = "presentations"
version = "0.0.1"
license = "None"
default_task = ["analyze", "publish"]


@init
def set_properties(project):
    # define unittest coverage properties
    project.set_property("coverage_threshold_warn", 50)
    project.set_property("coverage_break_build", True)
    # define linting properties
    project.set_property("flake8_break_build", False)
    project.set_property("flake8_max_line_length", 120)
    project.set_property("flake8_verbose_output", True)
    # define documentation properties
    project.set_property("sphinx_builder", "html")
    __location__ = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
    project.set_property("sphinx_config_path", os.path.join(__location__, '../docs'))
    project.set_property("sphinx_source_dir", os.path.join(__location__, '../src'))
    project.set_property("sphinx_output_dir", "_build/")
```

However, when I run the pyb command to build the package, pybuilder does not generate the desired documentation. I think, I have yet to define another default_task in addition to "analyze" and "publish" in pybuilder's build.py file in order to force pybuilder to execute the sphinx plugin when running the pyb command.

The user [awwsmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2925434/awwsmm) has written a super helpful [tutorial on how to manage your python project with pybuilder](https://dev.to/awwsmm/managing-your-python-project-with-git-and-pybuilder-21if). He also confirms that it is difficult to find a definit list of all available attributes and properties of pybuilder online. Unfortunately, the suggested search on [pybuilder's core code](https://github.com/pybuilder/pybuilder/blob/master/src/main/python/pybuilder/core.py) doesn't help me either.

Does anyone know how to deal with that problem? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

I am coding on a windows machine using python (3.6.13), pybuilder (0.11.17) and sphinx (4.0.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding sphinx_generate_documentation to the default tasks and altering the sphinx plugin properties does the trick. The new build.py looks like:

```
# import required packages
from pybuilder.core import use_plugin, init
import os
import sys
import inspect

# import required plugins
use_plugin("python.core")
use_plugin("python.unittest")
use_plugin("python.install_dependencies")
use_plugin("python.flake8")
use_plugin("python.coverage")
use_plugin("python.distutils")
use_plugin("python.sphinx")

# define build attributes
name = "presentations"
version = "0.0.1"
license = "None"
default_task = ["analyze", "publish", "sphinx_generate_documentation"]


@init
def set_properties(project):
    # define unittest coverage properties
    project.set_property("coverage_threshold_warn", 50)
    project.set_property("coverage_break_build", True)
    # define linting properties
    project.set_property("flake8_break_build", False)
    project.set_property("flake8_max_line_length", 120)
    project.set_property("flake8_verbose_output", True)
    # define documentation properties
    project.set_property("sphinx_builder", "html")
    project.set_property("sphinx_config_path", "docs")
    project.set_property("sphinx_source_dir", "src/main/python")
    project.set_property("sphinx_output_dir", "docs/_build")
```